# How to add new line of row in devexpress gridcontrol?(WinForms C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to add a new line of row when pressing a button. In datagridview it would be:
datagridview1.Rows.Add()

What is the equivalent code for that in gridcontrol? Please help me.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot add a new row directly to your `GridControl`, since this is just a container for the views. However, if you're using a `GridView` inside your `GridControl` (or any other descendant of ColumnView), you can add a new row using `AddNewRow()` method.

```
(myGridcontrol.MainView as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView).AddNewRow();
```

[Link to documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_AddNewRowtopic)

EDIT: You can access your view in a different way, of course.

Comment: In spite of my comments below, this so indeed the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The DevExpress `GridControl` must always be bound to a datasource: you cannot add rows directly to the `GridControl` object or its child `GridViews`.

Instead, you must bind your `GridControl` to a data source (via the `GridControl.DataSource` property), and add/remove rows via this data source.

See the ['Binding To Data'](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument634) documentation at the DevExpress site for more information on the kinds of data sources that can be used with a `GridControl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AddNewRow to add new row and SetRowCellValue to insert value to that row.

```
yourgridViewName.AddNewRow();
yourgridViewName.SetRowCellValue(rowhandle,columnName,value);
gridViewMappedFileds.UpdateCurrentRow();
```

Put yourgridName.RowCount-1 for rowhandle to insert the row at last.Put gridViewMappedFileds.Columns["ColumnName"] to give your columnname.