# fill specific column gridcontrol devexpress

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid, gridcontrol

I want to fill a specific column in a gridview. I want to do this with code, but I have already established the column in the gridcontrol as how you can see in the picture.

[established Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA7d1.png)

This is my code to fill the column, but I don't know what to do to fill that specific one column using name or fieldname or whatever it takes.

```
GridControl1.DataSource = Nothing

SQL.ExecQuErY("SELECT nombre FROM productos")

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SQL.Exception) Then MsgBox(SQL.Exception) : Exit Sub

For Each row As DataRow In SQL.DBDS.Tables(0).Rows

        ?????? THIS IS WHERE IT'S SUPPOSED TO GO THE INSTRUCTION TO FILL THE COLUMN ??????

Next
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing your for loop with `GridControl1.DataSource = SQL.DBDS.Tables(0)`. That should bind the data to your grid. No need to copy row by row.

Comment: @FloatingKiwi yeah thanks, actually that's how I use to fill a gridcontrol when I dont have columns in the gridview already, but I want to fill that specific one column that is established with the data of the query.

Comment: Devexpress follows fairly closely to the windows grid so what I'd do in that is set `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false` and `myColumn.DataPropertyName = "nombre"` and it should setup the binding for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind the data to your grid like this :

```
Sql.ExecQuErY("SELECT nombre As colNombre FROM productos")
GridControl1.DataSource = Sql.DBDS.Tables(0)
```

`FieldName` of column in `GridControl` must have same name of Field in `DataSource`.

or you can change `FieldName` of column in `GridControl` to `nombre` and use your initial query :

```
Sql.ExecQuErY("SELECT nombre FROM productos")
GridControl1.DataSource = Sql.DBDS.Tables(0)
```

Comment: YES! This is the answer that I was looking for, thanks. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19077245/770710) on another SO thread.

[How to add new line of row in devexpress gridcontrol?(WinForms C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062111/how-to-add-new-line-of-row-in-devexpress-gridcontrolwinforms-c)

It may direct you to correct way of implementation. You must have some backing data source assigned to grid control to add row at run time and assign only the one column value to the grid using the SetRowCellValue method.

There are lots of question on DevExpress support related to such implementation. Please follow the below references:
[Creating Columns and Binding Them to Data Fields](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument639)
[ColumnView.AddNewRow Method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_AddNewRowtopic)
[Add new row to xtragrid through code](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q279331)
[Add New Row to GridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q456331)
[Adding new row to gridview](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q524021)
[Adding gridView columns at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/DQ12202)
[GridView: Add column in runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q492849)
[how to add columns to xtragrid dynamically at runtime and also how to add repository items to those columns dynamically??](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q294517)

Hope this help..